# Use of “ist” or “sind” with “die Leute”

Tags: grammatical-number

In one of my German writing tests, I have the following sentence:

> a) Die Umgebung ist sehr nett, jedoch ist die Leute ein bisschen unfreundlich.

This has been checked by my teacher and she says it is correct but it just sounds wrong. I would expect it to be

> b) Die Umgebung ist sehr nett, jedoch sind die Leute ein bisschen unfreundlich.

since I believe *Leute* to be a plural. Although I am aware that German cannot always be translated into English, to me, this sentence would mean

> The surroundings are very nice, however the people is a bit unfriendly.

However, there may be a simple German rule that I am not aware of. Who is correct?

Comment: Note that the first verb needs to be *ist,* as *Umgebung* is singular.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft thanks. So does that make the second verb ist or sind?

Comment: "ist" neither sounds nor is correct. If it looks like a plural, it has to quack like a plural - German doesn't have idiomatic mis-concord like "the police are busy" or "the data is informative".

Comment: It's not impossible for a noun to change from English plural to German singular: "My pants are green" -- *Meine Hose ist grün.* That's not the case here though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looking around I found this in http://german.about.com/library/weekly/aa021206a.htm

> [Leute] is a common informal term for “people” in general. It is a
>   word that only exists in the plural. (The singular of Leute is
>   die/eine Person.)

Which seems to indicate that the correct form is

> Die Leute sind

I have never seen *die Leute ist*.

Comment: Thank you. All of my instincts told me that it should sind but since my teacher had checked it I thought I was missing myself.

Answer (score 0):

I quote the vocabulary:

> die Leute Pl., kein Sg.

die Leute, plural, no singular conjugation.
So, I guess "die Leute ist" is wrong.

Comment: What does this add to the other answer?